# How to use toupper() function to count both lowercase and uppercase user input?

Tags: c, arrays, toupper

I have an array of size 25 that stores capital letters in an array. It stores, for my user input test, 'A', 'B', 'C', and 'D'. My program counts the amount of those letters in the array and prints it out. For example, if AABBCCDD was entered, it would say there are 2 A's, 2 B's, 2 C's and 2 D's. Now, I am trying to get it to accept lower case letters as well and count them as long as they are the same as the uppercase. For example, if I entered, aA,Bb, cC and dD, it would still print that there are two of each. MY code is the following:

```
int main(void)
{
    char array[25];

    printf("Enter array: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", array);
    printf(Array is: ", array);

    count(array, 'A');
    return 0;
 }
 void count(char* array, char p)
 {    
 int i, count = 0;
 for (i = 0; array[i] !='\0'; i++)
   if(array[i] == p)
     count++;
 printf("Number of %c's: %d\n, p, count);
 }
```

I want the code to count both 'a' and 'A'. Is using toupper() the approach?

Comment: `p = toupper((unsigned char)p);` before loop .. `if(toupper((unsigned char)array[i]) == p)`

Comment: Exactly correct! thank you

Comment: @CodeFreak If that's what you have, and it works, then what is the question?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY any idea why there is a warning for implicit declaration of function toupper?

Comment: @CodeFreak have you included `ctype.h`?

Comment: @babon I accidentally had it as ctye.h, so yes that was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Is `&` both upper case and lowercase or neither?

Comment: this line: `for (i = 0; array[i] !='\0'; i++)` says to exit the loop when entry contains '\0'  However, the array is not initialized to a known value and could have a '\0' anywhere within the array.  Suggest: `char array[25];` be changed to: `int array[25] = {0};` and this: `for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(array_/ sizeof(int); i++)` be changed to: `for (i = 0; array[i] !='\0'; i++)`.  There are several other problems with the posted code, Of most importance is the posted code does not compile, due to several syntax errors.

Comment: it is a very poor practice to make the name of a function be the same as a local variable inside the same function.

Comment: strongly suggest read only one character at a time, treat `array[]` as an array of integers,  use the read in character as the index into the array, similar to: `array[ toupper(charvalue) - 'A']++;`   Then when printing the results ignore array elements that are still 0.  When inputting characters to update the array, do not process input characters that are not `isalpha()`

Comment: @user3629249, be careful, as you don't check bounds on `array` which is defined as `array[26]` (well, it's defined erroneously as 25, not allowing for `Z` character counts, but this doesn't affect my comment)  you can receive a nonalpha char, like `'0'`, and try to access `array[ '0' - 'A' ]`, which is `array[ 48 - 65 ]` or `array[-17]` and have trouble.

Comment: @LuisColorado,  did you miss the part of my comment: `When inputting characters to update the array, do not process input characters that are not isalpha()`

Comment: @user3629249, it's not me who must read your comment, it's the asker.  If you post some code with errors, it's desirable at least to notify about them in some kind of marginal note, so the problem posted doesn't get worse.  You don't say how to process chars not alpha (perhaps @codefreak doesn't know about `isalpha(3)`)

Answer (score 1):

you just need to replace `if(array[i] == p)` conditional block with

`if(toupper(array[i]) == p)`

And if you are not sure about the case of p(p can be any of lowercase or uppercase) the replace it with

`if(toupper(array[i]) == toupper(p))`

Answer (score 0):

```
void count(char* array, char u) //pass only uppercase
 {    
    int i, count = 0;
    char l = tolower(u);      //get the lower
    for (i = 0; array[i] !='\0'; i++) {
        if(array[i] == u || array[i] == l)
        count++;
    }
    printf("Number of %c's: %d\n, p, count);
 }
```

BUT! For 26 letters of the alphabet, you are going over the string 26 times. Imagine the string would be 100+ characters long.
Try and make a solution that only goes over the string once.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the if in for loop with below snippet and it will solve your problem.

if(toupper(array[i]) == p)

In this case everytime the comaprison will be with uppercase of character and as you are passing the char to be counted as argument, make sure you pass it in upper case

I hope it helps.

Comment: I got an error that said "request for member 'toupper' is in something not a structure or union"

Comment: You need to pass like toupper(array[i]).